# iOS App Rejection - ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, ipv6

Apple rejected my app iOS app, i have been trying to get this app on the store for the past two weeks.

The app requires a demo account with an IP, port, account number, client number and account key. I created several accounts for apple with this information, but i just keep getting rejected.

At first it was due to the UIBackgroundModes for location which i needed to change for ios 9 and add a disclaimer.

I gave the apple developer doing the review all the information to gain access to the application. They rejected the app again noting: *Please note that apps are reviewed on an IPv6 network. Please ensure that your app supports IPv6 networks, as IPv6 compatibility is required.*

I'm currently using [reachability 2.2](https://gist.github.com/darkseed/1182373) to monitor the state of the device. This has worked perfectly for all tests under an IPv4 network.

Although there is a new version [reachability 3.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) that says it fully supports IPv6. Im not sure if reachability is up to date as they are still using AF_INET and not AF_INET6, outlined in the documentation. Apple has also removed reachabilityForLocalWiFi, but my app includes it and monitors IN_LINKLOCALNETNUM.

If it is possible how can i set up the IPv6 network on my iMac? The app uses the IP address (ex. 199.56.42.21) to initialize a connection with the server. I dont have a IPv6 network yet, so i tried setting up a IPv6 connection using my iMac from  [set up a local IPv6 Wi-Fi network using your Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW16). The problem is my iMac runs behind a proxy (using ethernet), and the external network is on wifi and on the setup guide it says *not through wifi*.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, really. It's network configuration.

Comment: basically you need to be sure you have updated all `NSULRConnection` to `NSURLSession` in your project, and that is pretty much the first step of having joy.

Answer (score 1):

I am using *reachability* 3.x and it supports IPV6.

I have tested it personally over an IPV6 network. Our App has also gone through the App Store review just fine.

If you are using any other network libraries, please use below link to test IPV6 support
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

Answer (score 1):

Just registered your website with any CDN like [cloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) and your app will be approved next time no need to shift the whole site to any other server. This is the easiest way to get approval from app store.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) is the most recent version of the Internet Protocol (IP), the communications protocol that provides an identification and location system for computers on networks and routes traffic across the Internet.

The number of Internet-connected users, devices, and applications are growing at such a rapid clip that the pool of available addresses for the original version of the Internet Protocol, known as IPv4, is being rapidly depleted. IPv4 uses 32-bit addresses and can support 4.3 billion devices connected directly to the Internet. The replacement protocol, called IPv6, uses 128-bit addresses and provides approximately three hundred and forty trillion.

Nowadays, Apple rejects the applications because the apps should support the IPv6 network. In our environment, we have also faced the same situations for the apps and we have found one of the solutions for this problem. Most apps will not require any changes because IPv6 is already supported by NSURLSession and CFNetwork APIs.If your app uses IPv4-specific APIs or hard-coded IP addresses, you will need to make some changes.

Apple also recommends not to use IP address Literals, for the long term and Make sure you aren’t passing IPv4 address literals in dot notation to APIs such as getaddrinfo and SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName. Instead, we can use high-level network frameworks and address-agnostic versions of APIs, such as getaddrinfo and getnameinfo, and pass them hostnames or fully qualified domain names (FQDNs). If you are using AFNetworking Library, Please make sure to update it to version above 3.x, as they seem to have updated few of the things. We have to do some changes in AFNetworking library in class AFNetworkReachabilityManager

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
static AFNetworkReachabilityManager *_sharedManager = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
struct sockaddr_in address;
bzero(&address, sizeof(address));
address.sin_len = sizeof(address);
address.sin_family = AF_INET6; //Change AF_INET TO AF_INET6
_sharedManager = [self managerForAddress:&address];
});
return _sharedManager;
}
```

We need to make some changes in the above module for our app and add into the library. Once we have done this, we can test the app for IPv6 by enabling the internet sharing option in MAC.

**Test For IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Compatability**
First, we need to make, sure Mac is connected to the internet through Wi-Fi. Navigate to system preferences and select sharing option and make sure you need to hold down the option key before select the sharing option. Select the Internet Sharing and then select the create NAT64 network checkbox. Now we need to choose the network interface that provides your internet connection such as Ethernet, Wi-Fi, Bluetooth PAN.

Here i am selecting Wi-Fi to share the internet connection and configure the Wi-Fi network options.Once configured the Wi-Fi, then enable the internet sharing option.

Once we select the internet Sharing, it will ask prompt to start share the internet access for your device.

Now the IOS device got connected in the shared network and we can check the app is working on that network.